# Error "index out of range in self" while doing Back Translation with Python

Tags: python, translation, back

I'm trying to do Back Translation using:

> !pip install transformers
> !pip install sentencepiece
> from transformers import MarianMTModel,MarianTokenizer

This is what I have done:

First, I load both models: English to Spanish and viceversa.

> #Modelo Inglés a Español
> first_model_name = 'Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-es'
> first_model_tkn = MarianTokenizer.from_pretrained(first_model_name)
> model_en_to_es = MarianMTModel.from_pretrained(first_model_name)
>
> #Modelo Español a Inglés
> second_model_name = 'Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-es-en'
> second_model_tkn = MarianTokenizer.from_pretrained(second_model_name)
> model_es_to_en = MarianMTModel.from_pretrained(second_model_name)

Then I use a function to format the texts:

```
#Formatear las frases
def format_batch_texts(language_code, batch_texts):
  
  formated_bach = [">>{}<< {}".format(language_code, text) for text in batch_texts]

  return formated_bach

# Test of the function
text_formated = format_batch_texts("es", text_Data_Unos)
print(text_formated)
```

Once the texts are formatted, I write another function to implement back translation:

```
#Translation
def perform_translation(batch_texts, model, tokenizer, language="es"):
    # Prepare the text data into appropriate format for the model
    formated_batch_texts = format_batch_texts(language, batch_texts)
    
    # Generate translation using model
    translated = model.generate(**tokenizer(formated_batch_texts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True))

    # Convert the generated tokens indices back into text
    translated_texts = [tokenizer.decode(t, skip_special_tokens=True) for t in translated]
    
    return translated_texts

# Check the model translation from the original language (English) to French
translated_texts = perform_translation(text_formated, model_en_to_es, first_model_tkn)
print(translated_texts)
```

But when I run this last cell, this error appears in this line of the code:

> translated = model.generate(**tokenizer(formated_batch_texts,
> return_tensors="pt", padding=True))

**Error: index out of range in self**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-66a8e09cf9d7> in <module>()
     13 
     14 # Check the model translation from the original language (English) to French
---> 15 translated_texts = perform_translation(text_formated, model_en_to_es, first_model_tkn)
     16 print(translated_texts)

10 frames
<ipython-input-23-66a8e09cf9d7> in perform_translation(batch_texts, model, tokenizer, language)
      5 
      6     # Generate translation using model
----> 7     translated = model.generate(**tokenizer(formated_batch_texts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True))
      8 
      9     # Convert the generated tokens indices back into text

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py in decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
     25         def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
     26             with self.clone():
---> 27                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     28         return cast(F, decorate_context)
     29 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/generation_utils.py in generate(self, inputs, max_length, min_length, do_sample, early_stopping, num_beams, temperature, top_k, top_p, typical_p, repetition_penalty, bad_words_ids, force_words_ids, bos_token_id, pad_token_id, eos_token_id, length_penalty, no_repeat_ngram_size, encoder_no_repeat_ngram_size, num_return_sequences, max_time, max_new_tokens, decoder_start_token_id, use_cache, num_beam_groups, diversity_penalty, prefix_allowed_tokens_fn, logits_processor, renormalize_logits, stopping_criteria, constraints, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, output_scores, return_dict_in_generate, forced_bos_token_id, forced_eos_token_id, remove_invalid_values, synced_gpus, exponential_decay_length_penalty, **model_kwargs)
   1171             # and added to `model_kwargs`
   1172             model_kwargs = self._prepare_encoder_decoder_kwargs_for_generation(
-> 1173                 inputs_tensor, model_kwargs, model_input_name
   1174             )
   1175 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/generation_utils.py in _prepare_encoder_decoder_kwargs_for_generation(self, inputs_tensor, model_kwargs, model_input_name)
    523         encoder_kwargs["return_dict"] = True
    524         encoder_kwargs[model_input_name] = inputs_tensor
--> 525         model_kwargs["encoder_outputs"]: ModelOutput = encoder(**encoder_kwargs)
    526 
    527         return model_kwargs

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1108         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/marian/modeling_marian.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, head_mask, inputs_embeds, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    746             inputs_embeds = self.embed_tokens(input_ids) * self.embed_scale
    747 
--> 748         embed_pos = self.embed_positions(input_shape)
    749 
    750         hidden_states = inputs_embeds + embed_pos

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1108         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py in decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
     25         def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
     26             with self.clone():
---> 27                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     28         return cast(F, decorate_context)
     29 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/marian/modeling_marian.py in forward(self, input_ids_shape, past_key_values_length)
    138             past_key_values_length, past_key_values_length + seq_len, dtype=torch.long, device=self.weight.device
    139         )
--> 140         return super().forward(positions)
    141 
    142 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py in forward(self, input)
    158         return F.embedding(
    159             input, self.weight, self.padding_idx, self.max_norm,
--> 160             self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)
    161 
    162     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2181         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2182         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2183     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2184 
   2185 

IndexError: index out of range in self
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please, add the stack of the error description, or at least some lines if it's too large, so we can see which call produced the index out of range error.

Comment: I've added a picture of the full error.

Comment: Not pictures, please. Copy and paste as text.

Comment: I've copied each line of the error output

Comment: After a quick tour in the examples of the transformers documentation, my feeling is that the `generate` method is unpacking the tokens, which you try to do again with the `**`. I would suggest try one of these: `translated = model(**tokenizer(formated_batch_texts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True))` (without the generate method) OR `translated = model.generate(tokenizer(formated_batch_texts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True))` (without unpacking the tokens).